# How to pass the selectedItem value of listView to another page in wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

I m not so familiar with wpf so need help.
I want to pass the value of the selected item in listview to another page textbox using binding.
I have successfully got the selected value but don't know how to pass that on another page.
Please help

```
    <ListView x:Name="mobileList" Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.Row="6" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
              Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataList,Mode=TwoWay}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ModelName,Mode=TwoWay}"
                                Header="ModelName" Width="auto"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

    <TextBlock x:Name="txtModelID" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ModelID, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2" 
               Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               FontSize="10" Height="20"/>


    <TextBlock x:Name="txtModelName" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.ModelName, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" 
               Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               FontSize="10" Height="20"/>


    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBrandID" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.BrandID, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="4" 
               Grid.Column="1" Background="Gray" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               FontSize="10" Height="20"/>
```

This is the Selected Item

```
private CK_Model _SelectedItem;
    public CK_Model SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Is your page where you want to bind the text box is embedded in the same XAML of the list view?

Comment: no its not embedded in same pagei want the selected value on another page

Comment: Is this new page hosted in the same window and hence it's viewmodel could be instantiated by the window viewmodel hosting your original or not? Your window viewmodel could instantiate this other page's viewmodel and just pass the SelectedItem property ( bad name - already got a meaning) to it.

Comment: @Andy it helped me to solve the error thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setter:

```
    private CK_Model _SelectedItem;
    public CK_Model SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _SelectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
            _anotherPageViewModel.YourProperty = _SelectedItem;
        }
    }
```